# How to realloc a struct in a function

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic, realloc

I want to add a new word, read from keyboard, to my dictionary with a function made by me, increasing his priority.

here is my try. When i run this code, i get this message : Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct dictionary_entry{
    char *word;
    int priority;
};
void adauga_cuvant(struct dictionary_entry **dictionar, int Lungime, char cuvant[21]){

    *dictionar = realloc( *dictionar, (Lungime)*sizeof(struct dictionary_entry));
    dictionar[(Lungime)]->word =(char *) malloc(strlen(cuvant)*sizeof(char *));
    strcpy(dictionar[(Lungime)]->word, cuvant);
    dictionar[(Lungime)]->priority = 1;
}
int main() {
    int N, M, i;
    char aux[21];
    struct dictionary_entry *dictionary;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    dictionary = (struct dictionary_entry *)malloc(N * sizeof(struct dictionary_entry));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%s", aux);
        dictionary[i].word = (char *)malloc( strlen(aux) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dictionary[i].word, aux);
        dictionary[i].priority = 0;
    }
    scanf("%s", aux);
    N++;
    adauga_cuvant(&dictionary, N, aux);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].priority);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: If you store the result from `realloc` in the same pointer you used as an argument to `realloc` then you'll leak the previously allocated memory if `realloc` fails.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point, how I can fix the problem then?

Comment: That particular issue (that is unlikely connected to the problem you asked about) is simply fixed by assigning to a temporary variable first and checking if it's `!= NULL` before assigning it to the "real" variable.

Comment: Can you help me with the sequence of Code? Still doesn t work.

Comment: In adauga_cuvant() `dictionar[(Lungime)]->` is not right - dereferencing at the wrong levels and out of bounds. It should probably be `(*dictionar)[ Lungime - 1 ]. `. (*dictionar) is your pointer to the start of your array. The way you have it would be for pointer to first element of an array of pointer to struct rather than the pointer to pointer to first element of array of struct that you are actually trying to use. This is an ambiguous construction in the language that the compiler can't distinguish between.

Comment: You `malloc(strlen(aux)` - but that doesn't make room for the `\0` that `strcpy` will put there.

Comment: Similar to @TedLyngmo's point, `malloc(strlen(cuvant)*sizeof(char *))` needs one more _and_ should be char's, not char *'s